# How can I edit my savegames?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

In previous SCS games, savegames were in text format, so you could easily edit them. The `.sii` files used for savegames in Euro Truck Simulator 2 seem to be in some binary format instead.

Is there a way I can edit my savegames?

Comment: Unbinarize?? If this word does exist, then it's ambiguous. You have the source, but not the target. You are converting something from binary to what? Hex? Oct? Dec?

Comment: This would mean one would have to reverse engineer the format of the binary save files. Unless one is good at reverse engineering file formats and has the time to invest in such a venture it probably wont happen. You would have to wait until someone does or do it yourself.

Comment: The first four bytes (ScsC) are the file header but I can't discern the structure of the rest.

I suspect they're either compressed or encrypted, as compressing them increases the file size (which is indicative of a high entropy level).

Comment: He probably meant `Decrypt .sii files`

Answer (score -2):

ETS2 is a pain in the ass when it comes to editing savegames. I have found a [nifty tool on the truckersmp forum](https://forum.truckersmp.com/index.php?/topic/53015-ets2-savegame-editor/). Maybe give that a try?

There is a full explaination on how to edit the save game.
Best of luck.